# Incomprehensible infinite backward loop C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am new to C++ and I am trying to achieve a backward for loop, I founded solutions which works very well but I want to know what my version is not correct and making an infinite loop.

Here is a working version that I founded (I don't understand how we can decrease `i` in the condition..) :

```
for (unsigned i = size ; i-- > 0 ; )
{
  // do stuff with i
}
```

Here is a version I wrote which works but don't go down to 0 (this way seems more logical to me) :

```
for (unsigned i = size-1 ; i > 0 ; i--)
{
  // do stuff with i
}
```

If I say for exemple `n=10`, I will get this if I `print` `i` in the loop :

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

And here is the version which for me is the more logical and should go down to zero but is providing an infinite loop.

```
for (unsigned i = size-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
  // do stuff with i
}
```

Could someone explain to me why the last version isn't working and what is the best choice to make ?

Comment: It's an unsigned integer. When you subtract 1 from 0 qua unsigned int, you get a very large positive number rather than -1, because -1 isn't in the range of values representable as unsigned integers. Change it to a signed int (if your upper limit is in the range representable in that data type).

Comment: Thank you @Hammerite ! I didn't know that

Comment: [This reference should tell you all you need to know.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows)

Comment: Worth noting since you start from "size": the c++11 provide `std::rbegin()` and `std::rend()`, so iterate-able  containers can be iterated backwards by `for (auto it = std::rbegin(values); it != std::rend(values); ++it) { std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(values), it) << std::endl; }`,

Comment: A good compiler of code analyser should warn that such condition is always-true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `unsigned` number is *always* >= 0. (When it reaches zero a further decrement sets it to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()`)

So your final `for` loop is equivalent to

`for (unsigned i = size-1 ; true ; i--)`

which, of course, loops forever.

In your first loop, you have  `i-- > 0` as the stopping condition. When `i` is zero, `i--` is an *expression* with value zero (so the loop halts), despite the fact that `i` is then set to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()`. Some folk like (me included; cue the downvotes) to write `i-->0` and regard `-->` as the *slide operator*. See [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator)

Comment: Thanks ! Can you tell me more about the `i--` in the condition for the first version ? I didn't that was possible..

Comment: Added that. It's rather elegant, if a little hard to follow, especially at 3am when you're debugging something! Perhaps therefore worth avoiding.

Comment: That's a good question! It really depends on your field and so is subjective. I'm a scientific programmer so *love* the `-->` idiom, especially when working with `unsigned` types. When I retire all my poor colleagues will be expected to understand the idiom. But I think that could be the exception rather than the norm. Another approach would be to use `signed` types, or use a different loop structure.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I will go for the `unsigned` types

Answer (score 2):

The statement `i >= 0` is always true because `i` is `unsigned` which means that is never below zero. If you decrease the value while `i` is zero, there will occur a so-called underflow and it will have a very high number.

The first version certainly gets the job done, so I would stick to it.